# Can I infer the hypotenuse given only $a > b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

Today, I came up with a problem. The problem is this:

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be the sides of a right-angled triangle, such that $a > b$. The nature of $c$ is unknown. Can I infer the hypotenuse given only this data?

Resolution:
The sides of all right triangles should follow: $$ hypt \gt adj1 \ge adj2 $$
Where $adj1$ and $adj2$ are the remaining, adjacent sides.
I then do a simple permutation of the hypotenuse within the above to uncover all the possibilities:

Possibility 1. $$ a (hypt) \gt b(adj1, adj2) \ge c (adj1, adj2) $$
Possibility 2. $$ a (adj1, adj2) \lt b (hypt) $$
$$ b (hypt) \gt c (adj1, adj2) $$
Possibility 3. $$ a (adj1, adj2) \le b(adj1, adj2) \lt c(hypt) $$

Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please, avoid chit-chating in your questions.

Comment: Much better, thank you.

Comment: You can infer that $b$ is not the hypotenuse. Beyond that, nothing else can be inferred. However, if you're given more information, e.g. you're told it is an isosceles right triangle, naturally you can conclude $a$ is the hypotenuse.

Comment: See what you can infer from these Pythagorean triples $$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
n & k=1 & k=2 &k=3 & k=4 & k=5\\ \hline
Set_1&3,4,5 &5,12,13&7,24,25&9,40,41&11,60,6\\ \hline
Set_2&15,8,17&21,20,29 &27,36,45 &33,56,65&39,80,89\\ \hline
Set_3&35,12,37&45,28,5&55,48,73&65,72,97&75,100,125\\ \hline
Set_{4}&63,16,65&77,36,85&91,60,109&105,88,137&119,120,169\\ \hline
Set_{5}&99,20,101&117,44,125&135,72,153&153,104,185&171,140,221\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Comment: These are all the possible right triangles whose lengths are all integers. The closest to equality the triangle's “legs” can get — without the hypotenuse *not being an integer* — is explicited in the 1st element of $Set_1$, 2nd element of $Set_2$ and last element of $Set_4$. There are no Pythagorean triples $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ where $ a = b  \land c\in \Bbb Z$. I'll exercise my right to take my leave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a right-angled triangle with $a>b$, there are 3 possibilities:

$$a> b\geq c\\
a> c\geq b\\
c> a > b
.$$

$a$ is the hypotenuse in the first two cases; $c$ is the hypotenuse in the last case.